# sd card reading and writing speed

Tags: android

I need to find out the speed of reading and writing in sd card in android. Any idea in that.. I can read and write files to sd card and can also get the total size of the file. I want to know the best way of doing it.

Comment: I think that depends on the processor of the Device

Comment: and the Class your Sd card is of... Class 6 and above is considered fast enough for tasks where you require speed in read/write

Answer (score 0):

If you know the size of the file you just read, take the time stamp before you open the file and after you close the file the compute: `(time_after-time_before)/file_size`. this will give you the reading speed.

Do the same for writing.